# How to make an mutable C array for this data type?

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays

There's this instance variable in my objective-c class:

```
ALuint source;
```

I need to have an mutable array of OpenAL Sources, so in this case probably I need a mutable C-array.

But how would I create one? There are many questions regarding that:

1) How to create an mutable C-array?

2) How to add something to that mutable C-array?

3) How to remove something from that mutable C-array?

4) What memory management pitfalls must I be aware of? Must i free() it in my -dealloc method?

Comment: What do you need it for? Why are you assuming you need a C-style array? By the way, i don't think that community wiki fits here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d keep things simple. `ALuint` is some kind of `int`, so that you can easily wrap it using `NSNumber` and stick it in an ordinary `NSMutableArray`:

```
ALuint bar = …;
NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray array];
[foo addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bar]];

// and later
ALuint source = [[foo lastObject] intValue];
```

Comment: good point... however, would be good to know how to do something in c, when performance matters. allocacting objective-c objects is very heavy.

Comment: It is not. It can make a difference when you’re writing a particle engine with dozens of thousands of particles to be recalculated at 50 fps. In the remaining 99.9 % of cases the bottleneck is going to be elsewhere.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question. I came here looking for an answer to the same question as per the title, and this doesn't help :(. Apple's API's frequently require C arrays as input, and in many cases you need a mutable array. I was looking for something better than "cast void* pointers all over the place and look forward to hard crashing your app one day"